# Question about probability interpretation formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $0<p<1$ y $0\leq k\leq n$. Prove that $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=1$$
I know how to prove this using mathematical analysis. But my probability teacher say that, there is an interpretation of this using Probability.

I have seen an example: A coin is tossed until obtaining $k$ crowns if $n$ pitches are needed then in the first $n-1$ pitches we have $k-1$ shields. Then the probability of that $n$ pitches are nedeed is $$\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$ and as it is a probability must satisfy $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=1.$$ But i don't know how to interpret the first general sum.

Comment: You are almost there, think of what happens if the coin is not fair, and the probability of of obtaining a crown is $p$

Comment: Ohh Thanks i think i understand you. If $p$ is the probability of obtain a crown then just apply the reasoning of the example. I'm really grateful I had not seen that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the probability of "success" on any trial is $p\ne 0$. We repeat the experiment independently until we get $k$ successes. Let random variable $X$ be the number of **trials** until the $k$-th success.

We have $X=n$ if there were exactly $k-1$ successes in the first $n-1$ trials, followed by a success on the $n$-th trial.

The probability of $k-1$ successes in $n-1$ trials is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}$. (This is a straight binomial distribution problem.)

Multiply by $p$. We get
$$\Pr(X=k)= \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

Now argue that with probability $1$ the experiment terminates. So
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \Pr(X=n)=1.$$